# GRUB Boot 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.3

Tags: boot, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu from a CD and it has no alongside OS running and I can't get to the normal Ubuntu home screen but when I boot it comes up with

> GNU GRUB  version 2.02beta2-9ubuntu1.3 Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions#

Answer (score 0):

1. boot install cd
2. connect to internet
3. install boot-repair
4. run boot-repair